# TypeScript 3.9 with HTML5 Canvas -- error on .strokeStyle

Tags: javascript, typescript, html5-canvas, typescript-typings

Not sure how to resolve the issue, but I am facing an error that won't let color the strokes of the line:

```
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas')! as HTMLCanvasElement;

canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

const c = canvas.getContext('2d');

c?.fillRect(100, 100, 100, 100)

c?.beginPath();
c?.moveTo(50, 300)
c?.lineTo(300, 100)
c?.lineTo(400, 300)
c?.strokeStyle = "red" //<=== error occuring
c?.stroke()
```

The error is : `TS2779: The left-hand side of an assignment expression may not be an optional property access.`

Looking deeply in the library, I see that its interface, `CanvasFillStrokeStyles` is correctly identifying `fillStyle`:

```
interface CanvasFillStrokeStyles {
    fillStyle: string | CanvasGradient | CanvasPattern;
    strokeStyle: string | CanvasGradient | CanvasPattern;
    createLinearGradient(x0: number, y0: number, x1: number, y1: number): CanvasGradient;
    createPattern(image: CanvasImageSource, repetition: string | null): CanvasPattern | null;
    createRadialGradient(x0: number, y0: number, r0: number, x1: number, y1: number, r1: number): CanvasGradient;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) `?.` in JavaScript (and therefore in TypeScript) 
permits *reading* the value of a property located deep within a chain of connected objects without having to expressly validate that each reference in the chain is valid.  It does *not* allow you to [assign properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining#Optional_chaining_not_valid_on_the_left-hand_side_of_an_assignment).  This functionality was [considered but deferred to a possible future proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining/issues/18).

For now, if you want to assign a property to something that might turn out to be `null` or `undefined`, you will have to write that code yourself without using `?.`:

```
if (c !== null) c.strokeStyle = "red"; // okay
```

---

In fact, given that you keep using `?.` on the same object makes me think you'd be happier just checking that object for nullishness *once* and then using regular property access after that:

```
if (!c) throw new Error("Where's my 2d context?!");
c.fillRect(100, 100, 100, 100)
c.beginPath();
c.moveTo(50, 300)
c.lineTo(300, 100)
c.lineTo(400, 300)
c.strokeStyle = "red"
c.stroke();
```

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBMCGYBu8IwLwwCYmAVwFsBTMKAOgEc8iAnATwGUiAbI4KEGgCgHIFlUPAJQBCGKhgAJACoBZADIBhRCggBRVsVIBuALAAoA-1VkA7gEssUABYYYFsDlNlzYMLQDqlm3v3HUZNZE5gDm1rCYDk4ubrSSwWFQvkbg0HB2-hBkIURQiuBQRAAeULwATFjCyX4A-GQAZubMzABKbKUAjAAMXQA0MN19Az39g0IGRnUARkQhrgAK8DZcQtowk2QEIEhE0iBcAKxDAMw947VkzK67+6dDYxtX7ntcACwjMHfn5vUwXMAwEToTBgPDNIRwMjQGggADWRAYUDorDsACIaEQsKiNtC4UQVhNDPofn8RMAITYYaYYO5qWoaDDuKiPEEMTw0AQ6DAKnACsUoDURKjVkYGk1Wu0uINRh9pcMuudgGQZnMwItliK-JttjdDiczqKnrq7jKFYbri93vqzVrcfDEciiGiMVjRXb8ZqgA)

Comment: Good to know that optional chaining does not allow assign properties. Will keep this in mind in the future. Thank you!